# TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) - Why? What does it mean? How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

I was trying to use **react useContext** hook between search.js and result.js component but somehow it's not working.

I want to send data from one component to another. using props is a bit complex so I decided to use context api. I added value as well but why it's not iterable? It's reaching the result component but that destructing line of contextApi is making a big issue here.

The error I am getting is **TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))**

*search.js code* ->

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router';
import './Search.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import vehicleData from '../Home/vehicleData.json';

export const PlaceContext = createContext();

const Search = () => {
    const [searchPlace, setSearchPlace] = useState({
    from: '',
    to: ''
})

const [route, setRoute] = useState({
    from: '',
    to: ''
})

const {type} = useParams();
let ride;

vehicleData.map(vehicle => {
    
    if(vehicle.Name === type) {
        ride = vehicle.Name;
    }
})


const handleBlur = (event => {
    const newSearchPlace = {...searchPlace}
    newSearchPlace[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setSearchPlace(newSearchPlace);
})

const history = useHistory();

const resultPage = rideOption => {
    const url = `/result/${rideOption}`;
    history.push(url);
    console.log("pacche");
  }

const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (searchPlace.from && searchPlace.to) {
        setRoute(searchPlace);
        console.log(searchPlace, " && ", route);
    }
}

console.log(searchPlace);

return (
    <PlaceContext.Provider value={[searchPlace, setSearchPlace]}>
        <div className="d-flex flex-column searchField">
            <div className="inputArea">
                <h4>From</h4>
                <input onBlur={handleBlur} name="from" id="fromField" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Starting Point" />
            </div>
            <div className="inputArea">
                <h4>To</h4>
                <input onBlur={handleBlur} name="to" id="toField" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Destination Point" />
            </div>
            <button onMouseEnter={handleClick} onClick={() => resultPage(ride)} className="checkBtn btn btn-success btn-outline-info btn-lg m-3">Check</button>
        </div>
    </PlaceContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

*and the result.js code* ->

````
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './Result.css';
import vehicleData from '../Home/vehicleData.json';
import { PlaceContext } from '../Search/Search';


const Result = () => {

    const [searchPlace, setSearchPlace] = useContext(PlaceContext);

    console.log(searchPlace);

    const {ride} = useParams();
    let transportOption = ride;

    let transportName, transportImg;

    vehicleData.map(vehicle => {
        if(vehicle.Name === transportOption) {
            transportName = vehicle.Name;
            transportImg = vehicle.imgUrl;
        }
    })
    
    return (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between showComponent">
            <div className="placeAndPrice">
                <div className="placeName">
                    <p>From : {}</p>
                    <p>To   : {}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-around pricePart">
                    <img src={transportImg}/>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-column priceBox">
                        <p>{transportName}</p>
                        <p>131 Taka</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mapBox">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7304.049644099905!2d90.3781836249269!3d23.746494238365205!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3755b8b0e848958f%3A0xd56e2e3180c6a3ce!2sKalabagan%2C%20Dhaka%201205!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbd!4v1616325753856!5m2!1sen!2sbd" loading="lazy"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Result;```



So what is the error and how to solve it?
````

Answer (score 0):

The error comes when you try to loop over a **non-iterable** entity. In your case `vehicleData` seems to be that object (**non-iterable**) instead of an array (**iterable**).

**EDIT** - I think the above would have given `.map is not a function`.
One thing I noted is that you are not actually having any `{children}` prop being used in the `PlaceContext.Provider` so how are you actually able to do the following :-

```
<Search>
<Result/>
</Search>
```

Ideally your `PlaceContext.Provider` bit should have following type of implementation :-

```
return (
    <PlaceContext.Provider value={[searchPlace, setSearchPlace]}>
        /* {Your own divs and bla bla} */
        {children} 
       /* the above will come from Search prop */
    </PlaceContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

You can directly use `Result` instead of `children` too if you don't have many `children` to consider.

Please check whether you implementation is in line with what is described here - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider

Comment: it's an array of 4 objects. now, what to do?

Comment: @mozadded Are you sure ? Can you log it ?

Comment: Array of objects are iterable.

Comment: console.log(vehicleData);

(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {Name: "Bike", imgUrl: "https://static6.depositphotos.com/1001941/653/v/95…6530511-stock-illustration-vector-racing-bike.jpg"}

1: {Name: "Car", imgUrl: "https://365psd.com/images/previews/204/red-car-vector-graphics-eps-59011.jpg"}

2: {Name: "Bus", imgUrl: "https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/bus_vector_275695.jpg"}

3: {Name: "Train", imgUrl: "https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images…th-backup-of-backup-of-model-train.jpg?1531675306"}

length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: @mozadded Check the updated answer. I think your `Provider` implementation is not right as per your use-case.

Comment: actually I am using route to go another component. so I wasn't working that wa if that's what you are asking.

Comment: in search.js component, I have logged it and got the desired result which i would like to send.

Comment: I am asking you to log it inside Result where you’re using it. Instead of using [searchPlace, setSearchPlace] just log the result of useContext like const result = useContext(PlaceContext); console.log(result)

Comment: it is saying undefined

Comment: Yeah so that’s the issue. I am pretty sure you have not wrapped Result inside your Provider. Just see how I have suggested in answer and follow React docs as mentioned for more.

Answer (score 0):

When I see your code, you are importing `vehicleData` from the json file (vehicleData.json) You may want to check if `vehicleData` is imported correctly by `console.log(vehicleData)`. If the data is imported as you expected, then please check if `vehicleData` is an array type. If not, you cannot use map function. If your data is an object type, then you can use something like following:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: yes, it is an array consisting 4 objects. map function is working.